# How to read data from an xml?

Tags: c#, xml, web, xmlnode

I am using a web service which returns the following xml.
in c # and I made the connection and returns an object of type XmlNode

I need to extract these values ​​primarily TIME_PERIOD = "2010" OBS_VALUE = " 4796580 "
I would appreciate help me

This is the XML

```
<CompactData xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xmlns:inegi="urn:sdmx:org.sdmx.infomodel.keyfamily.KeyFamily=inegi:TIPO_B_DSD:compact" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd urn:estat:sdmx.infomodel.keyfamily.KeyFamily=inegi:DSD_TIPO_B:1.0:compact inegi:DSD_TIPO_B_Compact.xsd">
<Header>
<ID>BISE</ID>
<Prepared>2016-05-10T20:00:51</Prepared>
<Sender id="INEGI">
<Name xml:lang="en">Instituto Nacional de Estadística y Geografía</Name>
<Contact>
<Name xml:lang="en">Atención a usuarios</Name>
<Email>
http://www.inegi.org.mx/inegi/contacto/default.aspx
</Email>
</Contact>
</Sender>
</Header>
<inegi:DataSet>
<inegi:Series INDICADOR="1002000001" COBER_GEO="07000 " FREQ="V" DECIMALS="0" TOPIC="000400010001" NOTE="9,49,115,422,425">
<inegi:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2010" OBS_VALUE="4796580" OBS_STATUS="D" OBS_UNIT="Número de personas" OBS_SOURCE="487" OBS_NOTE="115,425"/>
</inegi:Series>
</inegi:DataSet>
</CompactData>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
XmlNode dataNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name()='CompactData']/*[local-name()='DataSet']/*[local-name()='Series']/*[local-name()='Obs']");
String obsValue = dataNode.Attributes ["OBS_VALUE"];
String timePeriod = dataNode.Attributes["TIME_PERIOD"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to ignore the namespace and use code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement obs = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Obs").FirstOrDefault();

            string TIME_PERIOD = obs.Attribute("TIME_PERIOD").Value;
            string OBS_VALUE = obs.Attribute("OBS_VALUE").Value;
        }
    }
}
```